# Better way to join arrays vertically without any common attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, concatenation

**Input:**

```
a=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

b=[[7,8], [9,10]]
```

**Output:**

```
c= [[1,2,3,7,8][4,5,6,9,10]]
```

**I am using**

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  c[i] = a[i].concat(b[i]);
}
```

Is there any better way to do this, using any JavaScript built-in functions?

Comment: if your code works this site is better http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If output is exactly as desired then what is wrong with the method?

Comment: @depperm That's quite a big `if` since he is missing some things in the output. Besides, this would be closed as hypothetical or stub code.

Comment: Even if some framework exposes a more convenient to type method to converge arrays at each index, the underlying logic is not likely to be any different than what you have shown.  So I guess the question, is what is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: @depperm: You've posted numerous comments today about moving questions to Code Review, and now all of them have been great.  Please be sure to read our [Help Center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: I just want to know if there is any in-built function in 'js' that does this for me, otherwise I am good. Sorry that I was no clear about this in my question. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

What you have looks perfectly fine, one loop and it's simple and readable - for good measure, here is basically the same thing using array methods if you prefer a slightly more functional (albeit trivially different) approach.

```
var a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];

var b = [[7,8], [9,10]];

var c = a.map(function(el, i) {
   return el.concat(b[i]);
});

console.log(c); // => [[1,2,3,7,8], [4,5,6,9,10]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another nowadays example use **[destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**.

```js
var a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
var b = [[7,8], [9,10]];

var c = a.map((el, i) => {
   return [...a[i], ...b[i]];
});

console.log(c);
// → [[1,2,3,7,8], [4,5,6,9,10]];
```